# div element with arrow

Tags: css

I'm trying to show a div element which has an indication arrow pointing to the top right.
I'm using CSS and HTML. I cant seem to sort out the CSS correctly.
Note: I don't want to use any images just pure code.

Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.arrow {
 float: right;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-color: #fff #fff #000 #fff;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 15px 20px 15px;
}
</style>

<div class="arrow"> </div>
```

Comment: thanks for ur help. can u please guide me to design a login div like ups.com. just go to www.ups.com and click on login button then a floating login div appear. how to generate this type of div. please help me if possible. thanks

Comment: see his other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377345/design-a-floating-login-div-issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use position:relative to move a div in a specific position example code:

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
}
.wrapper .arrow {
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:#03F;
}
```

**live example:** http://jsbin.com/iviha4