# design a floating login <div> issue

Tags: html, css

can anyone please guide me to design a login div like ups.com. just go to www.ups.com and click on login button then a floating login div appear. how to generate this type of div. please help me if possible. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting position as `fixed` or `absolute`, and set `top` and i.e. `left` properties. Looking at ups.com they use something like this:

`#loginform { position: absolute; left: 409px; top: 21px; width: 270px; }`

On top of this they use a transparent gif for the arrow and then a div inside with the styling of grey background and border.

Edit:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html> 
            <html> 
              <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                  header { background: black; color: white; padding: 2em;  }
                  #login { position: absolute; top: 5em; 
                  background: #eee; border: solid 1px #999; 
                  width: 200px; height: 200px; }
                </style>
              </head>
              <body>
                <header>
                  <button>Login</button>
                  <form id="login"></form>
                </header>
              </body>
            </html>
```

When it comes to hiding or showing the form I think JamWaffles post is good. jQuery is one of several ways to go, but probably one of the better. If not best. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for ur answer & effort. can u please provide me sample html & css code to design like a div at design time at ur free time.thanks once again.

Comment: Sure! I've added a short example above. I'm quite new at SO but I hope this is the correct way to reply. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make a `div` with a CSS style `position: absolute; z-index: 100`. This will position the div on top of all content (`z-index`) and without moving it from it's position, set by using `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right`. These four numbers are in pixels and are relative to the HTML canvas.

To display the floating div, set it's `display` CSS to `display: none`. Then, using JavaScript, or jQuery, make it so that clicking the login link will show the popup div, lik this (jQuery):

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="login_link">
<div id="login_form">
    -- form contents --
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#login_form
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: /* Whatever padding you need */;
    bottom: /* Whatever padding you need */;
    left: /* Whatever padding you need */;
    right: /* Whatever padding you need */;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#login_link").click(function() {
    $("#login_form").show()      // Can be .fadeIn() too
});
```

Hope this helps,

James

Answer (score 1):

You could always check how they did it, seeing as how you know a working example.

Install firebug on Firefox (http://getfirebug.com/) or use Chrome's built-in debugger - in both cases right click the div and select "Inspect element".

You can learn the basic theory behind relative and absolute positioning at http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ and check their code for details.